# How can I fix the error of "The kernel has died, and the automatic restart has failed."?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Closer\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1543, in _execute
    result = yield result
  File "C:\Users\Closer\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1099, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Closer\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 260, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Closer\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1107, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Closer\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 73, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "C:\Users\Closer\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1099, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Closer\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 260, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Closer\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1107, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Closer\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 79, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\Closer\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1099, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Closer\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 260, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Closer\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1107, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Closer\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 92, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\Closer\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1099, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Closer\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 260, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Closer\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 315, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Users\Closer\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 148, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Closer\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Closer\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 259, in start_kernel
    **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Closer\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 204, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Closer\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 128, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Closer\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Users\Closer\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 644, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

This is the error I am getting. 
I was using Python 3 and then I tried to move to python 2 for some reason. I uninstall anaconda and then again install for python 2.Whenever I am opening jupyter notebook, I am getting the message saying,

> The kernel has died, and the automatic restart has failed. It is possible the kernel cannot be restarted. If you are not able to restart the kernel, you will still be able to save the notebook, but running code will no longer work until the notebook is reopened.

I tried the [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673530/i-am-using-jupyter-notebook-ipython-3-on-windows-whenever-i-am-starting-my-pyt/51249097#51249097) provided, but still getting the same error.
I already wasted more than 6 hours trying to fix. It will be highly appreciated if someone please help me to fix the problem.

Comment: If python3 worked fine, you could try to reinstall Anaconda3 and then create an environment containing python2 (`conda create -n py27 python=2`)

Comment: Actually, before uninstalling anaconda for the first time, I tried this. But then again I uninstalled anaconda.